# SQL Server XML result, convert to JSON using C#, and JavaScriptSerializer()?

Tags: c#, json, list, dictionary, javascriptserializer

Ok, I'm a little stuck here. I can get my query and return my data as XML. That's not the problem.

I can create an XDocument. That's not the problem.

What I would like to be able to do is turn my XML:

```
<DATA>
<row>
    <PersonName>Hank Scorpio</PersonName>
</row>
<row>
    <PersonName>Sgt. Pepper</PersonName>
</row>
<row>
    <PersonName>Dr. Sheldon Cooper</PersonName>
</row>
</DATA>
```

Into JSON. I tried using the dictionary, and something like this:

```
var d = xdoc.Descendants("row")
.ToDictionary(val => val.Element("PersonName").Name.LocalName, val => val.Element("PersonName").Value);
```

But that kept giving me a duplicate value error.

Then I considered using a List of strings instead of a dictionary. I'm a bit reluctant to do that, though.

I only have 1189 records to do, but my fear is if it grows too much, even with the given capacity of a list, it may not be the best way to go.

So basically I want to turn the above XML into something like this:

```
{
  "DATA": {
    "row": [
      { "PersonName": "Hank Scorpio" },
      { "PersonName": "Sgt. Pepper" },
      { "PersonName": "Dr. Sheldon Cooper" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or, to save myself some strife, should I just go ahead and do the list? For the application I am building this for, I am sending the values to an API, but they're currently deciding if they also want an ID for the record. So I'm trying to figure out a solution that won't require a large re-write should they change their minds later.

We're using VS2015, so I don't think we have some of the newer C# features.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: you got multiple personname field and all keys in dictionary must be unique, that's why you are getting duplicated key error. Try use a XML serializer to serialize the xml into an object and then use js serializer to serialize it into json

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to convert the contents of all the individual rows into a single dictionary.  That won't work because all the xml row contents have the same key, "PersonName", whereas dictionary keys must be unique.

What you really want to do is convert each xml row into its own dictionary and then put those dictionaries into a list.  That is essentially what your desired JSON represents, along with a couple of wrapper objects.

With that in mind, here is how you would convert your XML to your desired JSON:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var obj = new
{
    DATA = new
    {
        row = xdoc.Root
                  .Elements("row")
                  .Select(r => r.Elements()
                                .ToDictionary(el => el.Name.LocalName, 
                                              el => el.Value))
                  .ToList()
    }
};

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = jss.Serialize(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to get my serialized JSON:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(queryResult, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

            var elementList = xdoc.Descendants("row").Select(r => new
            {
                PersonID = r.Element("PersonID").Value,
                PersonName = r.Element("PersonName").Value
            }).Distinct().ToList();

            jsonResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(elementList);
```

And my deserialization looked like this:

```
dynamic deserializedJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(result);
```

And I iterated over it like this:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> d in deserializedJson)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d["PersonName"]);
            }
```